# How to delete a line found by text from a TMemo control?

Tags: delphi, tmemo

I'm having a `TEdit`, `TMemo` and a button. When the user presses the button, I want to delete from that memo control a line matching the text entered in the edit box. If no matching line is found, some sort of *"line not found"* message should be displayed.

I'm new to Delphi and don't know any code for this, but in theory it should work on the principle of searching the `TMemo` until it finds a line that matches `Edit.Text` and then deletes that specific line.

Could someone show me how to delete a line found by text from a `TMemo` control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`IndexOf`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Classes.TStrings.IndexOf) function to find the index of an item by text in a string list. If this function returns value different from -1, the string was found and you can delete it from the list by using the [`Delete`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Delete) method passing the found index:

```
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Index := Memo.Lines.IndexOf(Edit.Text);
  if Index <> -1 then
    Memo.Lines.Delete(Index)
  else
    ShowMessage('Text not found!');
end;
```

Note, that the [`IndexOf`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Classes.TStrings.IndexOf) function is case insensitive.

Comment: Do note that `IndexOf()` will compare entire lines.  If you need to do a substring search instead, you will have to loop through the `Memo.Lines` manually, eg: `Index := -1; S := Edit.Text; for I := 0 to Memo.Lines.Count-1 do begin if Pos(S, Memo.Lines[I]) <> 0 then begin Index := I; Break; end; end; If Index <> -1 then ...`

Comment: @Remy, there's still quite a few interpretations of this question and I hope my edit did not break it down (review is always welcomed ;-) And feel free to take my post (code, or anything you like) and include it into some canonical answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! this helped me and did exactly what i wanted it to!! really big help!